# Submit form from greybox window to main window

Tags: zend-framework, forms, popup, submit

I'm using [greybox](http://orangoo.com/labs/greybox/advance_usage.html) and trying the following thing: I want to make a form inside the pop-up so when the users submit's it, the request goes to the main window and the pop-up closes.

I know the way to close the window is by using onclick="parent.parent.GB_hide()", but I really haven't been able to find a way to make the pop-up close and the data sent to the corresponding controller when the form is submitted.

I'm using Zend FW.

Thanks in advance,
I really appreciate what this community does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code given below at the end of the loop

parent.parent.GB_hide();